# How to cause button click event when enter is pressed in an hta application

Tags: batch-file, button, hta, enter, onkeypress

I have a script that allows me to hide a folder on my pc (using batch file). I've just implemented an hta application to it for the password so It's more seccure. Now the problem I'm having is that if I want to press enter to submit the form on the hta application, it just clears the password field and does nothing. I would like it to have the same effect as if I were to push the OK button. This is the hta part of my batch file:

```
:HTA
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Password Entry</title>
    <hta:application id="htaid"
    applicationName="Password"
    border="thin"
    borderStyle="normal"
    caption="yes"
    contextMenu="no"
    maximizeButton="no"
    minimizeButton="yes"
    navigable="yes"
    showInTaskbar="yes"
    singleInstance="yes"
    sysmenu="yes"
    version="0.1">
    <script language="vbscript">
        window.resizeTo 210, 110
        Sub SaveBatch()
            set fs=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            strFile=fs.GetAbsolutePathName(fs.BuildPath(fs.GetSpecialFolder(2), "UserIn.bat"))
            set ts=fs.OpenTextFile(strFile, 2, True)
            ts.WriteLine "set PASSWORD=" & document.Forms(0).elements("password").value
            ts.Close
        End Sub
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form style=margin-top:-15;>
        Password:
        <br><input type=password name=password>
        <br><input type=button language="vbscript" value="OK" onclick="SaveBatch : Window.Close">
    </form>
    <script language=vbscript>
        document.Forms(0).elements("password").focus
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I've tried creating a method that checks for keycode 13 onkeypress, also tried implementing it into the html portion of the password field. It either does what it did before, or causes a script error.

Answer (score 1):

Try my modification code and tell me if this did the trick or not ?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Password Entry</title>
<hta:application id="htaid"
applicationName="Password"
border="thin"
icon="wlrmdr.exe"
borderStyle="normal"
caption="yes"
contextMenu="no"
maximizeButton="no"
minimizeButton="yes"
navigable="yes"
showInTaskbar="yes"
singleInstance="yes"
sysmenu="yes"
SCROLL="NO" 
SHOWINTASKBAR="Yes"   
SELECTION="no"
MINIMIZEBUTTON="no" 
>
</head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="MSThemeCompatible" CONTENT="YES"> 
<BODY TOPMARGIN="1" LEFTMARGIN="1"><CENTER><DIV><SPAN ID="ONSCR"></SPAN></DIV></CENTER></BODY>
<script language="vbscript">
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Window_OnLoad
    CenterWindow 250,150
    Call PasswordForm()
    Call TextFocus()
end sub
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
    Dim iLeft,itop
    window.resizeTo x,y
    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2
    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2
    window.moveTo ileft,itop
End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub SaveBatch()
    set fs=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strFile=fs.GetAbsolutePathName(fs.BuildPath(fs.GetSpecialFolder(2), "UserIn.bat"))
    set ts=fs.OpenTextFile(strFile,2,True)
    If PasswordArea.value <> "" Then
        ts.WriteLine "set PASSWORD="& PasswordArea.value
        ts.Close
        self.Close 'To close this HTA after saving the password as a variable into UserIn.bat
    else
        Msgbox "The password entry is empty ! "& Vbcrlf & "Please type again your passowrd",VbExclamation,"The password entry"
        Location.reload(true) 'To reload this HTA again
    end if
End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub PasswordForm()
    Self.document.title = "My Password Enrty"
    Self.document.bgColor = "#BBBFFF"
    ONSCR.InnerHTML="<center><FONT COLOR=""#FFFFFF"" SIZE=""+1"" FACE=""VERDANA,ARIAL,HELVETICA,SANS-SERIF"">Password Entry</FONT<br>"_
    &"<input type=""password"" name=""PasswordArea"" size=""20"" onKeyUp=""TextFocus""><P>"_
    &"<input type=""Submit"" STYLE=""HEIGHT:25;WIDTH:110"" value=""OK"" onClick=""SaveBatch"">"
END Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub TextFocus
    PasswordArea.Focus 
End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I copy and pasted your code and it works, and now I'm trying to figure out how it works when pressing enter with your code. Theres on onkeypress or onkeydown event handling so I'm pretty clueless haha

Comment: The code is very simple; if you look on it; it show you how to create a password form using the method InnerHTML and we use the type Submit instead of the type button, so when you hit enter, he submit your input and execute the sub SaveBatch() and it close the HTA using Self.Close or Window.Close
You can take a look at this example Matrix Login + Simulation DOS
==> http://pastebin.com/NcK5nkFV

Answer (score 1):

I have just finished writing this batch that generate a HTA BOX to hide a password in CommandLine , so i want to share it with you !

Don't forget to vote for it if you like it !

```
@echo off
Title Generate a HTA BOX to hide a password in CommandLine Copyright Hackoo 2014
mode con cols=80 lines=5 & color 9B
Set MyVBSFile=%tmp%\%~n0.vbs
Set MyHTAFile=%tmp%\%~n0.hta
Call :CreateMyVBS
Cscript.exe //NOLOGO %MyVBSFile%
start /wait mshta.exe "%MyHTAFile%"
Del "%MyVBSFile%" & Del "%MyHTAFile%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%tmp%\userIn) do set "Mypassword=%%i"
echo Your password is : %MyPassword%
Del %tmp%\userIn
pause 
:#Start
<html>
<head>
<title>Password Entry</title>
<hta:application id="htaid"
applicationName="Password"
border="thin"
icon="wlrmdr.exe"
borderStyle="normal"
caption="yes"
contextMenu="no"
maximizeButton="no"
minimizeButton="yes"
navigable="yes"
showInTaskbar="yes"
singleInstance="yes"
sysmenu="yes"
SCROLL="NO" 
SHOWINTASKBAR="Yes"   
SELECTION="no"
MINIMIZEBUTTON="no" 
>
</head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="MSThemeCompatible" CONTENT="YES"> 
<BODY TOPMARGIN="1" LEFTMARGIN="1"><CENTER><DIV><SPAN ID="ONSCR"></SPAN></DIV></CENTER></BODY>
<script language="vbscript">
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Window_OnLoad
    CenterWindow 250,150
    Call PasswordForm()
    Call TextFocus()
end sub
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
    Dim iLeft,itop
    window.resizeTo x,y
    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2
    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2
    window.moveTo ileft,itop
End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub SaveBatch()
    set fs=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strFile=fs.GetAbsolutePathName(fs.BuildPath(fs.GetSpecialFolder(2),"UserIn"))
    set ts=fs.OpenTextFile(strFile,2,True)
    If PasswordArea.value <> "" Then
        ts.WriteLine PasswordArea.value
        ts.Close
        self.Close 'To close this HTA after saving the password as a variable into UserIn.bat
    else
        Msgbox "The password entry is empty ! "& Vbcrlf & "Please type again your passowrd",VbExclamation,"The password entry"
        Location.reload(true) 'To reload this HTA again
    end if
End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub PasswordForm()
    Self.document.title = "My Password Enrty"
    Self.document.bgColor = "lightblue"
    ONSCR.InnerHTML="<center><FONT COLOR=""#FFFFFF"" SIZE=""+1"" FACE=""VERDANA,ARIAL,HELVETICA,SANS-SERIF"">Password Entry</FONT<br>"_
    &"<input type=""password"" name=""PasswordArea"" size=""20"" onKeyUp=""TextFocus""><P>"_
    &"<input type=""Submit"" STYLE=""HEIGHT:25;WIDTH:110"" value=""OK"" onClick=""SaveBatch"">"
END Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub TextFocus
    PasswordArea.Focus 
End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</script>
</body>
</html>
:#End
::***********************************************************************************************
:CreateMyVBS
::'**********************************************************************************************
(
echo. Set fso = CreateObject^("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
echo. Set f=fso.opentextfile^("%~f0",1^)
echo. a=f.readall
echo. Set r=new regexp
echo. r.pattern = "(?:^|(?:\r\n))(?::#Start\r\n)([\s\S]*?)(?:\r\n)(?::#End)"
echo. Set Matches = r.Execute^(a^)
echo. If Matches.Count ^> 0 Then Data = Matches^(0^).SubMatches^(0^)
echo. WriteFileText "%MyHTAFile%",Data
echo. f.close
::'**********************************************************************************************
echo. 
echo. Function WriteFileText^(sFile,Data^)
echo.     Dim objFSO,oTS,sText
echo.     Set objFSO = CreateObject^("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
echo.     Set oTS = objFSO.CreateTextFile^(sFile,2^)
echo.     oTS.WriteLine Data
echo.     oTS.close
echo.     set oTS = nothing
echo.     Set objFSO = nothing
echo. End Function 
) > %MyVBSFile%
::'***********************************************************************************************
```